# Getting duplicate key error when elements are rendered inside a fragment without using a map

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I for the life of me can't figure out why this error is being thrown here, I'm using fragments all over my React Native app to render multiple root elements but only in this component am I getting the error being thrown

```
<VStack space={4}>
  <Text paddingBottom={3} fontWeight={"semibold"}>Community resource of the day</Text>
  {randomResource.status === "success" && (
    <>
      <ResourceCard resource={{ ...randomResource.data?.data, category: 2 }} />
      <Center w="full" key="test2">
        <Button variant="outlineRounded" size="xs" color="primary" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("BrowseResources")}>Show More</Button>
      </Center>
    </>
  )}
</VStack>
```

This is being rendered in a `ScrollView` for what it's worth but I haven't gotten that error before now, if I change the fragment to a `View` the error goes away, within the `ResourceCard` I don't have a map of any kind either

Can anyone point me in the direction as to why I might be getting this type of error when not rendering elements within a map?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65528177/11884052

Comment: @Quintis the Fragment is not in a `.map` statement though, I tried making the `<>` and `<Fragment key="some-key>` and I still get the same error

Comment: @PranjalKoshti Specifically the error is `Encountered two children with the same key, '.$.$.0'` If I add a key to each element within the `<>` it goes away, but why is this error happening here when it doesn't happen in other places. I've never had to add keys to elements within a fragment before, even within this same app I have fragments with elements that do not have keys and I don't get this error

Comment: @Jordan Big thanks for posting about your issue, I am running into the same exact error when dealing with a VStack with child elements and no inner FlatList or array map. It must have something to do with how the VStack works internally... In any case, specifying a unique key for each child element resolved the error.